# JGit move/rename folder issue on Suse linux

Tags: java, java-io, jgit, suse

I am facing an strange issue, i would like to move one sub-directory to another location in same Git repo using Jgit. Following code works on all operating systems but creating issue in Suse Linux 12. Some times it works as expected but few times it failed to move directory and delete new path.

```
final File oldMasterDataDir = new File(repoDir, "repoGlobal/oldLocation/xsd/VocabularyType");
final File newMasterDataDir = new File(repoDir, "repoGlobal/newLocation/xsd/VocabularyType");

@Override
public <T> void moveDirectory(final File pathSrc, final File pathDest, Properties properties)
   throws RepositoryException {
   try {
      Path sourcePath = Paths.get(pathSrc.getAbsolutePath());
      Path destinationPath = Paths.get(pathDest.getAbsolutePath());

      Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
// i have tried FileUtils.rename(pathSrc, pathDest); but same result
      if(pathDest.exist())
      final String gitPathSrc = toGitPath(pathSrc);
      final String gitPathDest = toGitPath(pathDest);
      getGit().add().addFilepattern(gitPathDest).call();
      getGit().rm().addFilepattern(gitPathSrc).call();

      properties.put(RevisionImpl.FILE_PATH, gitPathDest);
      commit("Audit migration done", properties);
      getRepository().tag("tag 1.1");
}else{
LOG.info("error while moving directory");
}
   } catch (final Exception e) {
      LOG.info("Error : File Not Found" + e.getMessage());
      throw new RepositoryException(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

I dont see any exception and "newLocation" gets deleted. I observed newLocation gets created for few seconds and then it got deleted. But i have no clue why is it happening on Suse linux only. Its working fine on Windows 7,8 and on RedHat perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was machine issue, we got another Suse 12 Sp2 environment and it is working fine.